# remove a string from a file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to remove a string from `text.txt`. `text.txt` file contains following format of string

```
text/more/more.txt
text/home.txt
text/more/yoo/yoo.txt
text/about.txt
```

Now what I am doing is watching a folder and when any of the above listed file, lets say `text/about.txt`, is deleted then `text.txt` file should automatically be updated to following

```
text/more/more.txt
text/home.txt
text/more/yoo/yoo.txt
```

For this I am using `hound` module to keep watching for delete event. And `replace` module to replace deleted path from `text.txt` file. Below is my code

```
watcher.on('delete', function(file, stats) {

    replace({
        regex: /file/g, // file is something like this text/about.txt
        replacement: '',
        paths: [path + '/text.txt'],
        recursive: true,
        silent: true,
    });

});
```

But my above code does not remove particular string i.e. `file` from `text.txt` file. **How can I solve this?**

**UPDATE**

`file` in above code has this value `text/about.txt`.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe take a look at the `file` variable. It could have special characters that need to be escaped before passing it in to your regex.

Comment: The only special character it has is `\n`. I am not sure if you are refering this as a special character or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a error in semantics, you misinterpreted what happens when you do this:

```
watcher.on('delete', function(file, stats) {
    ...
    regex: /file/g, // file is something like this text/about.txt
    ...
}
```

Here, `file` in the RegExp object is looking for a string called `file`, not the **actual** variable contents of the String object you're passing into the function. Do this instead:

```
    regex: new RegExp(file, 'g'), // file is something like this text/about.txt
```

See [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more details.

Comment: great it works now. But it does remove that `text/about.txt` but it also leaves the new line. How can I remove the new line including `text/about.txt`?

Comment: Like this: `regex: new RegExp(file + '\\n', 'g'),`.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated variable **search_content** and **replace_content** to handle special characters also and then using **fs** module to replace all strings in a file. Also you can run a synchronous loop on a files to replace strings using callbacks.

```
// Require fs module here.
var search_content = "file";
var replace_content = '';
var source_file_path = '<<source file path where string needs to be replaced>>';
search_content = search_content.replace(/([.?&;*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");//improve
search_content = new RegExp(search_content, "g");
fs.readFile(source_file_path, 'utf8', function (rfErr, rfData) {
    if (rfErr) {
        // show error
    }
    var fileData = rfData.toString();
    fileData = fileData.replace(search_content, replace_content);
    fs.writeFile(source_file_path, fileData, 'utf8', function (wfErr) {
        if (wfErr) {
            // show error
        }
        // callback goes from here
    });
});
```